# loop in a list of lists

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I am trying to use two foor loops for a variable with that has list within a list, but this code doesn't work. I get the error: list index out of range

```
D=[[12,10,13,14,13,-2,17,20,19,14],[9,-5,11,20,10,16,13,22,15,12]]

  # Replace negative values in demand list by 0
    for i in D:
        for j in i:
            if i[j] < 0:
                D[i][j] = 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your loop, `j` is not an index, it's the element, you can use `range` to loop over the indices (same thing about `i`, use `i[j]`, not `D[i][j]`, since `i` is a list):

```
for i in D:
    for j in range(len(i)):
        if i[j] < 0:
            i[j] = 0
```

Alternatively, you can use a list comprehension:

```
D = [[x if x >= 0 else 0 for x in d] for d in D]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `numpy` since it is containing numerical values numpy would be good:

```
D = np.array(D)
D = D.clip(0)
```

---

```
array([[12, 10, 13, 14, 13,  0, 17, 20, 19, 14],
       [ 9,  0, 11, 20, 10, 16, 13, 22, 15, 12]])
```

Answer (score 0):

For other solution,

```py
D = [list(map(lambda y: max(0, y), x)) for x in D]
```

Answer (score 0):

For minimum code change try using `enumerate`:

```
D=[[12,10,13,14,13,-2,17,20,19,14],[9,-5,11,20,10,16,13,22,15,12]]

  # Replace negative values in demand list by 0
    for i, sub_list in enumerate(D):
        for j, element in enumerate(sub_list):
            if element < 0:
                D[i][j] = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
D=[[12,10,13,14,13,-2,17,20,19,14],[9,-5,11,20,10,16,13,22,15,12]]
c=0
for i in D:
    #replacing 0 for every elements
    # this will also work for unlimited number of elements of any two dimentional list
    i=[0 if name<0 else name for name in i]
    print (i)
    D[c]=i
    c=c+1
print (D)
```